# Configuring Nginx Amplify when you are running multiple domains in same Server

Tags: nginx

I am using Nginx As API gateway. Same Ngnix is connected to multiple domains.

when I have tried configuring Ngnix Amplify for getting Ngnix Metrics Dashboards. I am getting metrics at whole server level but I am not able get it at domain level.

Anyone who has did this already or know how to do this.

Appreciate your help in Advance